# How to get yesterday's date in golang?

Tags: go, time

How do I get yesterday's date in the `time.Time` struct in Go?

Answer (score 166, accepted):

Here's one way with [`AddDate`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.AddDate):

```
time.Now().AddDate(0, 0, -1)
```

#### EDIT

The original answer also had a [`time.Add`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.Add) suggestion:

```
fmt.Printf("Yesterday: %v\n", time.Now().Add(-24*time.Hour))
```

See Vatine's comment for reasons to prefer `AddDate`.

Comment: I'd prefer `AddDate` to subtracting 24 hours. If nothing else, there's a small window where "subtract 24 hours" may get you into "2 days ago" (between 00:00 and 00:59, day after the spring DST transition) and one where it may get you to "today" (23:00-24:00, day of autumn DST transition).

Comment: .Add(-24*time.Hour) won't work. Mixing types. Will give error: invalid operation: -24 * time.Hour (mismatched types int and time.Duration)

Comment: what about `time.Now().Sub(24*time.Hour)`

Comment: @PeterOram You're not mixing types `-24 * time.Hour` is a valid expression. A Duration is an `int64` representing nano-seconds under the hood (`type Duration int64`), you can treat it like an integer. `time.Hour` is just a constant representing the amount of nano-seconds in an hour. A int64 is signed so you can absolutely have a negative Duration. The reason you're getting that error is because you're probably assigning a value to a variable before multiplying it against the duration, and that variable isn't being inferred as or converted to a Duration.

Comment: @ntsd I think `Sub` is misleading in the fact that it provides a difference between 2 times returning a duration. So `Sub` is a method of `Time` and take parameter of type `Time` and returns a `Duration`. So in your example you're providing a `Duration` instead of a `Time` and that won't compile, and even if it did you'd get back a `Duration` instead of a `Time`. I think it would have been handy to have a `Sub(v time.Duration) time.Time` and a `Difference(v time.Time) time.Duration` method, which would be more appropriately named IMO.